# How can I refresh a store in svelte?

Tags: svelte

In my svelte app I have a store with an empty list. The list might get populated later by an external function. How can I get the app to recognize the new data (in this case after two seconds have elapsed)?

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3321e6dc6e06485f93cd13b4d655527c?version=3.46.6)

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
    import Cars from './Cars.svelte'
</script>
```

**Cars.svelte**

```
<div>
    {#each $cars as car}
        <p>{car}</p>
    {/each}
</div>
<button class="select-button">Save</button>


<script>
    import { cars } from './store.js'
    $cars = $cars
</script>
```

**store.js**

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

let blank_cars = [];
let raw_cars = ['Audi', 'Aston Martin', 'BMW'];

export var cars = writable(blank_cars);

setTimeout(function() {
    cars = writable(raw_cars);
    console.log ('cars updated')
}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `set` instead of creating a new `writable`, like:

```
cars.set(raw_cars)
```

Working example: https://svelte.dev/repl/d2d602cd256844d883285c03b3537f9a?version=3.46.6